# Sharing project library via GIT

Tags: android, eclipse

A colleague and I share the same android project using GIT.

Now the problem is with the shared `FACEBOOK` library in `'project.properties'` since we do not have it on the same location.

He has it like this:
`android.library.reference.1=../../facebook-android-sdk-3.0/facebook`
and I have it like this:
`android.library.reference.1=../facebook-android-sdk/facebook`

So everytime one pulls a push from the other one has to correct the path. Is there a solution?

ps. deleting this file from the GIT repo is out of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got into the exact same problem with FacebookSDK library.

The solution is very simple and can be easily overlooked: **just add both lines to project.properties file**

So your project.properties should be like this:

```
android.library.reference.1=../../facebook-android-sdk-3.0/facebook
android.library.reference.1=../facebook-android-sdk/facebook
```

Every team members can have the lib on different location. That's fine, Eclipse will ignore the unresolved lib path(s) and just use the correct one.

It works for me and seems okay for a small team.

Answer (score 1):

there are 2 solutions for this:

1. moving the Facebook SDK to the git library and using it instead of your original FB SDK library.
2. adding `project.properties` to your `git.ignore` file.

Comment: how would I got about doing number 1?

Comment: assuming you have a folder, that is the host of all the projects for git, you copy and paste the FB SDK folder in there, do the `git add` magic and send that to your colleague

Comment: We have the project that is commited to GIT but facebook sdk was only cloned from the Facebook GIT page. 
So could you give me a more detail explanation how to achieve this then?